# error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'

Tags: python, opencv

The goal of this script is to compare an image (.png file) to a library of images (.png files) and return which image matches the best.

Below is the script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from patchify import patchify


# Define the path to the directory containing the images
image_dir = r'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Sample images\noise_samples'

# Load the query image
query_image_path = r'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Sample images\subject_samples\sub_2.png'
query_image = cv2.imread(query_image_path)

# Define size to resize the images
fixed_size = (600, 600)

# Define the size of the patches to be used
patch_size = (300, 300, 3)

# Define the step to be used for extracting patches
step = 300

# Define the colour format 
desired_colour_format = cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR


##############################################################################################################


# Resize the query image to a fixed size
query_image = cv2.resize(query_image, fixed_size)
assert query_image.shape[:2] == fixed_size, "Query image resize failed"

# Convert the image to the desired colour format 
query_image = cv2.cvtColor(query_image, desired_colour_format)
assert query_image is not None, "Query image colour format failed to convert"

# Extract patches from the query image
query_patches = patchify(query_image, patch_size, step)
print("Actual shape of query_patches:", query_patches.shape)

# Check query_patches data type
data_type = query_patches.dtype
print("Query image data type:", data_type)


##############################################################################################################
    

# Initialize a dictionary to store the matching scores for each image in the library
scores = {}

# Format the library images as the query image
for image_file in os.listdir(image_dir):
    # Load the image
    image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, image_file)
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Resize the image to a fixed size
    image = cv2.resize(image, fixed_size)
    assert image.shape[:2] == fixed_size, "Query image resize failed"
    
    # Convert the image to the desired colour format 
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, desired_colour_format)
    assert image is not None, "Query image colour format failed to convert"
    
    # Extract patches from the image
    image_patches = patchify(image, patch_size, step)
    
    # Check library image_patches shape and data type
    data_type = image_patches.dtype     
    print("Actual shape of image_patches:", image_patches.shape)
    print("Image data type:", data_type)
```

The outputs are as below. The input image and the library images seems to be a match.

```
Actual shape of query_patches: (2, 2, 1, 300, 300, 3)
Query image data type: uint8
Actual shape of image_patches: (2, 2, 1, 300, 300, 3)
Image data type: uint8
Actual shape of image_patches: (2, 2, 1, 300, 300, 3)
Image data type: uint8
Actual shape of image_patches: (2, 2, 1, 300, 300, 3)
Image data type: uint8
Actual shape of image_patches: (2, 2, 1, 300, 300, 3)
Image data type: uint8
Actual shape of image_patches: (2, 2, 1, 300, 300, 3)
Image data type: uint8
```

The following section is where I'm unsure on what to do.

```
# For all patches in row and column for the query image and library image
patch_scores = []
for i in range(query_patches.shape[0]):
    for j in range(query_patches.shape[1]):
        query_patch = query_patches[i,j,:,:,:]
        image_patch = image_patches[i,j,:,:,:]

        #patch1 = query_patches[i, j]
        #patch1 = patch1.reshape(patch_size)
            
        #patch2 = image_patches[i, j]
        #patch2 = patch2.reshape(patch_size)
        
        # Perform the matchTemplate
        patch_score = cv2.matchTemplate(query_patch, image_patch, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)[0][0]
        patch_scores.append(patch_score)
```

This is the full error that returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14708/3849403876.py in <module>
     86 
     87             # Perform the matchTemplate
---> 88             patch_score = cv2.matchTemplate(query_patch, image_patch, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)[0][0]
     89             patch_scores.append(patch_score)
     90 

error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1164: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
```

From what I can gather from searching the error online, it seems that the images are incompatible. I've tried standardising the colour format and size, as shown in the above output, but I still can't seem to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: welcome. please present a [mre] (missing imports, undefined functions). you're expected to debug your code. specifically, debug it at the site and time of the exception. inspect variables. compare them to what the violated assertion *requires* them to be.

Comment: What are your image data types and do they conform to what is required for matchTemplate?

Comment: @fmw42 data type is uint8. I believe it conforms to matchTemplete requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the resources @ChristophRackwitz. After adding .reshape(patch_size) before matchTemplate (I added it in as a comment in the question above), the script was able to execute without errors, although incorrectly (something I am still working on). I am unable to figure out the logic behind this when I've already define the size of the patch at the beginning of the script. This .reshape(patch_size) seems redundant.

Comment: likely issue with "patchify". contact author?